# AngularJS Date filter pass i18n locale for single invocation

Tags: angularjs, filter, internationalization

now i use "date" filter

```
{{ controller.day | date : 'EEEE - MMM d yyyy' }}
```

can i add something like 'locale'

```
{{ controller.day | date : 'EEEE - MMM d yyyy' : 'it-IT' }}
```

for locale the date in italian, but the rest of application remains in english?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
...convert the date in javascript
var convertedDateString = dateToConvert.toLocaleString();
var convertedDate = new Date(convertedDateString);

... later, in angular
{{convertedDate | date:'medium'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know where you're going (what's the point), but there are two ways to achieve your goal.

1. You can use [Angular Dynamic Locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) to load Angular L10n files dynamically. There is even a valid example how to set your target locale on it's GitHub page: `tmhDynamicLocale.set('it');`
2. You can create your own filter with arbitrary formatting. For instance you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format dates.

Personally, I would recommend first path. This will also format numbers according to a locale.

I definitely *not recommend* using vanilla JavaScript's `Date.toLocaleString();`. This function should always be given a locale as a parameter: `Date.toLocaleString(currentLocale);`. The only issue with the latter is support for [ECMA-402 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm), which is implemented by modern web browsers only. Should you need to support ancient web browsers (such as IE up to v. 10), you cannot expect it to work.